# C++ lambda capturing by copy of parent lambda's captured value

Tags: c++, g++, language-lawyer, clang++

Trying to compile the following code:

```
#include <functional>

void test() {

    int a = 5;

    std::function<void()> f = [a](){
        [a]()mutable{ // isn't it capture 'a' by copy???
            a = 13; // error: assignment of read-only variable 'a'
        }();
    };

}
```

gives the `error: assignment of read-only variable 'a'` error.

Changing the code by adding curly braces to `a` capturing:

```
#include <functional>

void test() {

    int a = 5;

    std::function<void()> f = [a](){
        [a{a}]()mutable{ // this explicitly copies a
            a = 13; // error: assignment of read-only variable ‘a’
        }();
    };

}
```

eliminates the compile error.
I'm wondering why is it so? Isn't the first variant equivalent to the second?

This is when using `g++` version 8.3.0 from Debian.

`clang++` version 7.0.1 compiles it successfuly.

Bug in `g++`?

Comment: Is the original `a` local? Global?

Comment: I tried with `a` local, haven't tried with global

Comment: Making both lambdas `mutable` makes g++ accept the code. Weird.

Comment: in case of global `a` the error (or should it be a warning?) is valid, as globals do not have to be captured, those are accessible from within the lambda even without capturing

Comment: @chi so, it is like `g++` captures the `a` by reference in that case

Comment: [clang and msvc are accepting code](https://godbolt.org/z/oe1n5q).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> [C++11: 5.1.2/14]: An entity is captured by copy if it is implicitly captured and the capture-default is = or if it is explicitly captured with a capture that does not include an &. For each entity captured by copy, an unnamed non-static data member is declared in the closure type. The declaration order of these members is unspecified. **The type of such a data member is the type of the corresponding captured entity if the entity is not a reference to an object, or the referenced type otherwise.**

The type of `a` inside your **mutable** lambda is `const int` because it was captured by copy from a `const int a` of enclosing **const** `lambda`. Therefore, making both lambdas mutable solves this issue.

Comment: I think there's some wonkiness here. I think it's actually specified that the inner `[a]` is referring to the original `int a  = 5;` not the data member of the closure type of the outer lambda. That is, in a lambda `[a]() { use(a); }`, `use(a)` is basically considered to reference the `a` that's in scope *as if the lambda weren't there*, and only then the lambda "intercepts" it. E.g. [try checking if `a` is `const` in the outer (`const`) lambda](https://godbolt.org/z/MKc6Pr). Then the inner capture list is referring to the non-`const` `int a`, and would capture non-`const`. GCC bug?

Comment: perhaps in that case the bug might be that `decltype(a)` is seeing outer `a`, rather than lambda's `a`, and both `g++` and `clang++` behave identically in this case, so it is either a bug in both compilers or some valid behavior we don't understand at the moment

Comment: That's the thing: I'm fairly sure that *there is no "lambda's `a`"*, according to the standard. The things inside a lambda refer to the things outside the lambda directly, and then the lambda intercepts them. So the inner capture list would refer to the outer `a`, make its own data member non-`const`, and *then* the outer lambda redirects the read of `a` used to initialize the inner lambda to its data member.